# 2001 Toyota Highlander Limited DRL not working

Tags: electrical, toyota, highlander, daytime-running-lights

I have tried the 7.5A fuse and the three relays without any success. What am I missing? What else could it be? The lightbulbs work. I’m out of ideas! They stopped working after a new battery was installed.

Comment: My Skoda has a configuration setting for the daytime running lights. One reason may be the setting was lost when the battery was changed. Another possible reason may be coincidental to the battery change – I have turned the DRL off, but one day I noticed they were on and I realised I was using the other key (of two). I then discovered that the car stores different personal settings for each key.